# SQL to produce subtraction from two different select query

Tags: sql

I have two select statements, lets say first output is
select Name, Score1, Score2, Score3, Score4 from table1;

```
Name    Score1  Score2  Score3  Score4
Ryan     42       50      32      35
Mark     58       47      38      44
John     41       43      52      58
```

lets say second output is
select Name, Score1, Score2, Score3, Score4 from table2;

```
Name    Score1  Score2  Score3  Score4
Ryan     42       52      38      39
Mark     51       87      52      28
John     60       50      42      62
```

In the final Query I would like to output subtraction of the numbers

```
Name    Score1  Score2  Score3  Score4
Diff1     0        2        6      4
Diff2     7        40      14      16
Diff3     19       7       10      4
```

I tried using the MINUS operator but it is not working as expected

Comment: MINUS is a set operation, the inverse of UNION

Answer (score 2):

You need to join the two sets on name so the values are all in one row, then subtract them

```
select
    t1.Name,
    t2.Score1 - t1.Score1 as Score1,
    t2.Score2 - t1.Score2 as Score2,
    t2.Score3 - t1.Score3 as Score3,
    t2.Score4 - t1.Score4 as Score4
from
    table1 t1
    join
    table2 t2 on t2.Name = t1.Name
```

Comment: watch out - he apparently wanted the absolute differences ...

Comment: @marcothesane yes I noticed that and left it as an exercise for OP to figure out once they got over the join hurdle

Answer (score 1):

You can use [abs()](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_mysql_abs.asp) function and a join operator to get the data you need.

here is the [query](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/3sXCgyh3Y5mXBMLnmuay9T/0):

```
select
    t1.name,
    abs(t1.score1-t2.score1) as score1,
    abs(t1.score2-t2.score2) as score2,
    abs(t1.score3-t2.score3) as score3,
    abs(t1.score4-t2.score4) as score4
from
    table1 t1
join
    table2 t2
on
   t1.name=t2.name
```

| name | score1 | score2 | score3 | score4 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Ryan | 0 | 2 | 6 | 4 |
| Mark | 7 | 40 | 14 | 16 |
| John | 19 | 7 | 10 | 4 |

Comment: watch out - he wanted the funny names "Diff<something>"

Comment: Thanks @marcothesane,  I will let the question author to confirm his intention on using diff1, diff2, diff3 in the question, whether it is just a short-hand for quick write-up or he indeed wants to use diffxxx as output names.

Answer (score 0):

.. and a third attempt - dragging the input with me as some input full-selects (replace my input full selects with your original queries ...)
In Oracle, you will need to add `FROM dual` at the end of every line starting with `[UNION ALL] SELECT ...`

```
WITH
-- your input ...
table1("Name",Score1,Score2,Score3,Score4) AS (
          SELECT 'Ryan',42,50,32,35
UNION ALL SELECT 'Mark',58,47,38,44
UNION ALL SELECT 'John',41,43,52,58
)
,
table2("Name",Score1,Score2,Score3,Score4) AS (
          SELECT 'Ryan',42,52,38,39
UNION ALL SELECT 'Mark',51,87,52,28
UNION ALL SELECT 'John',60,50,42,62
)
-- end of your input
SELECT
  CASE t1."Name"
     WHEN 'Ryan' THEN 'Diff1'
     WHEN 'Mark' THEN 'Diff2'
     WHEN 'John' THEN 'Diff3'
  END AS "Name"
, ABS(t2.Score1 - t1.Score1) AS Score1 
, ABS(t2.Score2 - t1.Score2) AS Score2 
, ABS(t2.Score3 - t1.Score3) AS Score3 
, ABS(t2.Score4 - t1.Score4) AS Score4 
FROM table1 AS t1
JOIN table2 AS t2 USING("Name")
ORDER BY 1;
```

| Name | Score1 | Score2 | Score3 | Score4 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Diff1 | 0 | 2 | 6 | 4 |
| Diff2 | 7 | 40 | 14 | 16 |
| Diff3 | 19 | 7 | 10 | 4 |